# Criação de um chat em português para dev Android

Tags: debate, chat

Eu reparei que há possibilidade de criar novos chats, como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sinto falta de um chat centralizado em Java Android, participo de grupos no Facebook e no LinkedIn, mas seria muito interessante termos uma sala de bate papo entre os dev's aqui no Stack Overflow PT.

Para não criar a sala e ficar lá sozinho aguardando por membros, resolvi postar aqui antes e já pra sanar algumas dúvidas também:

1. É necessário algum tipo de aprovação para criação do chat?
2. A única forma de divulgação do chat é pela [Listagem de salas](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não precisa de aprovação para criar salas. Só precisa de [privilégio, no  caso 1000 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms).

Até onde eu sei só existe a listagem mesmo. Você pode divulgar onde quiser se não ferir regras.

Mas já adianto que criaram outras salas especializadas antes e não foram pra frente. Depende de você conseguir que as pessoas participem.

Acho útil que tenha para as pessoas poderem perguntar o que não fica bem em um Q&A, ainda que eu ache que o [Estouro de Pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) já está bom para isso. Só temo as pessoas começarem perguntar coisas úteis no site principal no chat. Já vejo ocorrendo vez ou outra no EP e preferia que a pergunta estivesse no site mesmo. Perde-se perguntas ótimas que ajudaria muita gente. Tem caso que eu mesmo resolvo fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho que não foram para a frente porque a comunidade é relativamente pequena, já no chat geral do SOpt está pouca gente, quanto mais um de linguagem especifica...

Comment: Concordo com os dois.

Comment: Acho que não foram para frente porque poucos usuários sabem do chat. Estava tentando explicar uma resposta nos comentários e apareceu o link para continuar a discussão no chat, quando entrei na sala o usuário disse que não sabia que tinha chat.